# SSIS Odata connection successful but collection does not load, SSDT 2017

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, odata

I am trying to connect via an SSIS package within Visual Studio 2017 SQL Server Data Tools 2017 to an OData feed from Microsoft Dynamics 365 (hosted on the Microsoft Azure cloud).

The connection manager tells me when testing the connection "Test connection succeeded". However, when I want to specify this connection in the OData Source Editor it says "Unable to load collection for the connection xxxx, reason: cannot open this connection".

Interestingly, I am able to successfully connect to that OData feed and pull data via Power BI Desktop. This however is not practical as I cannot export data to a SQL Server DB from there.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, this is a super simple fix. Instead of adding the v9.1 at the end of the path, switch to v8.2 and the collections will pop up.